# Improve execution time of code so that it does not time out

Tags: python-3.x

I have a piece of code that works is some of case ,but some case this take more time and give time out issue.can someone please help to improve this?
[Edit]:let me explain the how it is working 
function  accepts a list as input
function  returns a list as output as follows:
1.The smallest number of list should be in middle
2.Next smallest number should be append at the end  of list
3.Next smallest number should be appended at the start of list 
4.Next smallest number should be append at the end  of list
5.Next smallest number should be appended at the start of list
4.it continues ......unless  we scan all input list

```
def pendulum(values):
    result=[]
    while(len(values)):       
        min_num=min(values)
        result.insert(0,min_num)
        values.remove(min_num) 
        if len(values)>0:
            min_num=min(values)
            result.insert(len(result),min_num)
            values.remove(min_num)
    return result
```

Comment: What is the code supposed to do, and what would be the typical input and expected output? You will get much more eager answerers if you don't force them to decipher your intention first.

Comment: What do you mean by *time out*? Do you mean to take a long time (I would expect that if `values` was large) or get stuck in an infinite loop?

Comment: Thanks Amadan,I have just edited it .

Comment: Hi Tim ,Yes you have rightly understood ,sorry if i could not capture it well.the code works well for small list size execution time increase as we increase the list size

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem is that your code searches for the minimum once per element. Pre-sorting the list will make it much faster. You are also inserting at the front of the list, which forces every element of the list to be moved, for every other element. To combat this, I just use `append`, and then reverse the front half of the list.

```
def pendulum(values):
    front = []
    back = []
    next_goes_to_front = True
    for value in sorted(values):
        if next_goes_to_front:
            front.append(value)
        else:
            back.append(value)
        next_goes_to_front = not next_goes_to_front
    return list(reversed(front)) + back
```